# Register event in jquery vs register event in html tag

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have 2 textboxes:

```
<input type="text" id="registerByTag" oninput="MyFunction()"/>
<input type="text" id="registerByJquery"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("#registerByJquery").bind("custominput",MyFunction);

       //use this to call the function: $("#registerByJquery").trigger("custominput");
    })
    function MyFunction()
    {
        console.log(this);
    }
</script>
```

When I trigger both textboxes, I get 2 different results.
On registerByJquery, I get the element registerByJquery (the element that triggered event);  On registerByTag, I get the whole HTML document object, I mean $(document) and not the element that triggered the event which is what I want to get.

1/ Why `this` is not returning the same result?
2/ Can I get the element that triggered the event if I register event by tag? I don't want to add parameters to MyFunction().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit `this` within functions called by inline event listeners

In order to access the element in the function you have to pass `this` or `event` in as argument

```
<input  oninput="MyFunction(this)"/>
```

---

```
function MyFunction(el)
{
    console.log(el);
}
```

---

Modern best practices are to use unobtrusive event listeners rather than inline ones. It helps the *separation of concerns* and since inline methods have to be in global namespace helps keep from polluting the global namespace and minimizing conflicts

---

Using jQuery can simply combine the events and  do

```
$("#registerByJquery").on("input custominput", MyFunction);
```

Doing so will make `this` available for both events

Comment: This is extractly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!